# I'm currently having trouble updating constraints for a UIVIew in Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I've created a custom View that has subviews added to it and a UIPanGestureRecognizer is added to each UIView object but when I select the UIView after I update the constraints there is a delay. If I drag the UIView (sView) off the screen, the next time I drag the view in either direction there is a delay of a few seconds before the pan gesture recognizer registers. It doesn't register the pan gesture immediately.

I've read up on auto layout and believe its configured correctly in the animation callback  method. I've created a delegate in the view controller that has access to the updated constraints, and sView.leftConstraint and sView.rightConstraint are fields I have added to a custom view that represents a draggable UIView.

The ScrollViewController adopts a protocol so that it can access the view that was selected and update the constraints accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
extension ScrollViewController: DragDelegate {

func draggedLeft(sView: DraggableView) {
    print("Dragged Left")

    confirmationLabel.text = ""
    sView.selectionLabel.text = "Not Selected"
    sView.cornerRadius = 7

    sView.rightConstraint?.isActive = false
    sView.leftConstraint?.isActive = false
    sView.leftConstraint?.constant = 1
    sView.leftConstraint?.isActive = true
//        sView.widthConstraint?.constant = 300


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        sView.updateConstraints()
        self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
}


class OrderSelectionView: UIView {

var dView : DraggableView?
var dView2 : DraggableView?
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

//I need to set up all the constraints in this class
//This will act almost like a container view


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

    let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    dView = DraggableView(frame: frame)

    dView2 = DraggableView(frame: frame)
    guard let dragView = dView else {return}
    guard let dragView2 = dView2 else {return}

    dragView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dragView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: laundryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    let rightAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dragView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let leftAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dragView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    dragView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    dragView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    dragView.leftConstraint = leftAnchor
    dragView.leftConstraint?.isActive = true
    dragView.rightConstraint = rightAnchor

    self.addSubview(dragView2)

    dragView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let laundryLabel2 = createLaundryLabel(lTitle: "Dry", constant: 100)

    dragView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dragView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: laundryLabel2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    let rightAnchor2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dragView2, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -50)
    let leftAnchor2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dragView2, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    dragView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    dragView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    dragView2.leftConstraint = leftAnchor2
    dragView2.leftConstraint?.isActive = true
    dragView2.rightConstraint = rightAnchor2

}
```

Comment: Why set the setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded on views other than sView? I don't think this is your issue, but I would start with replacing the contentView and view with sView.

Comment: @Sethmr I assumed that the superview had to update constraints since the subviews are added to that superview. In this case the contentView. I'll give it a try and see if calling sView.setNeedsLayout() changes anything.

Comment: Maybe, but calling setNeedLayout on any view is setting it up for updating its layout in the next available ui update block. Calling layoutIfNeeded updates it immediately before applying code coming after itself in the current block (unless inside an animation). I look at SetNeedsLayout as a force trigger that will normally be unneeded, but is safer to just call it anyhow. LayoutIfNeeded is where the true magic lies. I wouldn't ever call setNeedsLayout inside an animation block. I would follow a setNeedsLayout on a view by a layoutIfNeeded on the same view.

Comment: This is how I would normally set up an animation after changing constraints on a given view:

self.view.setNeedsLayout();
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {;
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
};

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! makes it slightly clearer. Hmm strangely enough, I'm calling self.view.setNeedsLayout()  outside the animation completion block and self.view.layoutIfNeeded() inside but still no hope. Other than that, when the view is swiped left or right it moves according to the constraints. It's whenever the left or right side of the UIView is dragged or collides with the superview that the gesture takes longer to select. Cool if I post some extra code or even an image of emulator?

Comment: Code helps, an image of the emulator doesn't do much without far more context than I am willing to sort through.

Comment: @Sethmr So ultimately I've created a separate view which I've called OrderSelectionView() and this is added to a ViewController as a subview. I have a hunch that somewhere along the line, constraints aren't updating or there is a crucial line that refreshes the constraints or updates them. And for some odd reason whenever a UIView is dragged outside of the bounds of the screen or its superview, in this case the contentView of the ScrollView, the constraints take time to reset. I'm thinking of increasing the width of the scrollview. Could be a pan gesture problem too